# Can I have react-hooks/exhaustive-deps for a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I wrote this hook (there could be bugs, I haven't used it yet):

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import _throttle from 'lodash/throttle';

export function useThrottledCallback(cb, delay, ...deps) {
  const callback = useCallback(_throttle(cb, delay), deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    const lastCallback = callback;

    return () => lastCallback.cancel();
  }, [callback]);

  return callback;
}
```

Is there a way I can make the exhaustive-deps rule lint usages of this hook?

```
useThrottledCallback(() => (a + b + c)}, 100, [])
```

In this usage, I'd like to be notified that `a`, `b`, and `c` need to be in the dependency array.

Comment: There is a bug actually, you don't want to `...` your deps:  ((x,y,...z) =>[x,y,z])(1,2,[3]) === [1,2,[[3]]]

Comment: Ah, that's a good point. I think I was originally planning to pass a list of deps as regular arguments but you can see in my usage example that I didn't end up doing that. Nice catch!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It should be pretty easy. The [documentation says](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks#advanced-configuration):

> `exhaustive-deps` can be configured to validate dependencies of custom Hooks with the additionalHooks option. This option accepts a regex to match the names of custom Hooks that have dependencies.

So you'd want something like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    // ...
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": ["warn", {
      "additionalHooks": "useThrottledCallback"
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh man, why didn't I read the docs! Thank you so much!